# Spring JPA join tables with grouping

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to get data with grouping from the database using Spring JPA, my classes are :

**Employee.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String name;

    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    @Column(name="date_of_birth")
    private LocalDateTime dateOfBirth;
    private Double salary;
    @Column(name="marital_status")
    private String maritalStatus;


    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy")
    @Column(name="date_of_hire")
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime dateOfHire;
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="dpartment_id")
    private Department department;

    //security additions
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
    @JoinColumn(name="employee_id")
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**Department.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department implements Serializable{


    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL) @JoinColumn(name="department_id")
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>();

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="manager_id",nullable=true)
    private Employee manager;   
}
```

I'm trying to get the data from the sql query :

```
select Dep.id, Dep.name as department_name , sum(emp.salary) as total_salaries, count(emp.id) as employee_count, dep.manager_id  from employee emp  inner join department dep 
on emp.department_id = dep.id 
group by dep.id
```

I have tried the using

```
 query= EntityManager .createQuery("select new com.me.domain.DepartmentSummary( d, sum(e.salary), count(e.id) ) "
           + "  from Department d  inner JOIN d.employees e group by d.id  ");
            List items = query.getResultList();
```

but this `query.getResultList()` for some reason crashes with a `NullPointerException`.

I'm not sure what I have done wrong or if there is any other way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** 
test case callstack :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getLoadedCollectionOwnerOrNull(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:859)
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.AbstractCollectionEvent.getLoadedOwnerOrNull(AbstractCollectionEvent.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.InitializeCollectionEvent.<init>(InitializeCollectionEvent.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1847)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:549)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:428)
    at com.me.entities.Employee.hashCode(Employee.java:27)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:362)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:492)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:217)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.endCollectionLoad(Loader.java:1150)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1119)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:964)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:911)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2121)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3927)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1092)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1019)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:672)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.nullSafeGet(EntityType.java:290)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultRow(QueryLoader.java:446)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(QueryLoader.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:741)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:943)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:911)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1269)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:268)
    at com.me.services.DepartmentService.getDepartmentSummaries(DepartmentService.java:72)
    at com.me.services.DepartmentService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$fbe553f5.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:713)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:646)
    at com.me.services.DepartmentService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a1dbb849.getDepartmentSummaries(<generated>)
    at com.me.DepartmentServiceTest.getDepartmentSummaries(DepartmentServiceTest.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Whats the error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-grouping):

> Hibernate also does not currently expand a grouped entity, so you
>   cannot write group by cat if all properties of cat are non-aggregated.
>   You have to list all non-aggregated properties explicitly.

So in your case, you'd have to include all Department properties in the group by clause.